# URL shortener with good statistics

Tags: web-apps, hosted, statistics, url-shortening

I am looking for a good URL shortener, which can be either paid/free, but I need really good statistics with clicks, geo, etc.

I really like [goo.gl](https://goo.gl/), but it has a really simple list and I don't like the UI at all.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

## [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/)

It's one of the most famous url shorteners, you have probably seen bit.ly links on articles, and in tweets and YouTube video descriptions.

- Provides the ability to customize your links
- Provides detailed click and geo statistics

For example, if you created a link that looks like: `bit.ly/1z3MQET`, then you can easily view its statistics by simply appending `+` to the end of the link, `bit.ly/1z3MQET+`

Comment: Thanks! Is there somewhere a paid version where I get something more?

Comment: @КристиянКацаров Yes. A paid version adds more features and allows you to brand your own domain. More information here: http://support.bitly.com/knowledgebase

Answer (score -2):

> Google’s URL shortener is sleek, simple and efficient. But that is to
>   be expected from the internet’s powerhouse. Login with your Google
>   account to get a rundown of all your previous shortened URLs along
>   with a nice selection of statistics for that particular URL. View
>   total clicks, referrers, countries and platforms.
>
> Not all URL shorteners offer statistics, so it’s good to take
>   advantage. If you are not signed in when using Goo.gl, you will be
>   given the same shortened URL as someone before if you are both trying
>   to shorten the same URL. This then doesn’t give you access to personal
>   statistics for your URLs.

<sup>([source](http://www.marketme.co.uk/5-of-the-best-url-shorteners-available/))</sup>

[image: Goo.gl URL analytics tracks valuable information on clicks and referrers including what browser and computer platform they’re using.]

Comment: Copied text has been a pattern in all your answerrs. Please read this post: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/735/6834